# Submit form via ajax; Fallback method if javascript disabled?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a registration form where a user provides email, re-enter email, password, re-enter password, birth month, day, year.

The user clicks "Sign Up."

```
If (Javascript is Enabled) {

submit the form using ajax

} elseif (Javascript is Disabled) {

automatically fallback to traditional methods.

}
```

Note: Keep in mind that if a user properly fills out the form, both methods need to verify that the email address does not already exist in the database.

Comment: http://accessites.org/site/2007/02/graceful-degradation-progressive-enhancement/

Answer (score 5):

There's a pure HTML/JS approach you can take to achieve this. Use an `onsubmit` event handler in your form. If it executes it means that JS is enabled. Just `return false` from it to prevent normal submission. If JS is disabled, the form will submit normally through the `action` attribute.

```
<form action="nonAjaxSubmit.php" onsubmit="return ajaxSubmit();">...</form>

<script>
    function ajaxSubmit() { 
        // Submitting through ajax
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Take into account `onsubmit` is not called if you programmatically call `form.submit()` from javascript.